# Dynamics 365, drag and drop

Tags: c#, sharepoint

У меня на форме Dynamics 365 есть веб-ресурс HTML страница с зоной Drag and drop, как можно перетащенный файл загрузить в SharePoint?

Comment: а можно код зоны Drag and drop увидеть?

Comment: SharePoint как-то связан с Dynamics 365?